# Backand: updating registered user email and name

Tags: angularjs, backand

What is the best method for updating a registered user's email and/or names in Backand? How can I make sure that if I'm changing the email address that I'm not also disconnecting the registered user from their object in the users table (since the server side Update uses the email address to locate the user object in the table)?

I'm using the Backand SDK in my Ionic/AngularJS app.

Thank you for your help. I know it's probably simple but I'm just missing it.

Answer (score 1):

user email is the UserId in Backand, so you can't change it.
It's like you will try to change your email address in gmail, it's impossible.

But you can change firstName and lastName.

To do that go to you app dashboard in [backand.com](https://www.backand.com) and in enter to "Securtiy & Authorization" > "Registered users", in this tab you can change first and last name of your registered users.

[image]

Comment: Ygalbel, thank you for the answer but the email is not the UUID for a registered person (each registered user is given a 'RegId' that is unique to each user) so it should be changeable.

Comment: Also, let me clarify that I'm needing to be able to update the email, first name, and last name through the app and not via the app dashboard as I need to allow users to make the updates themselves.

Comment: In current version of Backand, email is the primary key to identify users. So you can't change. What you can do is to add another field and call him 'Display Email' that user will see, and you can change it.